# Finding a "best partial match" in a SQLite table without a partial index

Tags: android, sqlite, match, partial

In my Android app which uses SQLite to store user data I have a table called `valency` as shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS valency(urid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,typ INTEGER,entity INTEGER,v0 INTEGER,v1 INTEGER,v2 INTEGER,v3 INTEGER,v4 INTEGER,v5 INTEGER,lato INTEGER,data INTEGER DEFAULT 0);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS vTypEnt ON valency(typ,entity);
```

I need to find a "best" match for rows in this table for the columns `v0.. v5` for a defined value for the `typ`and `entity`columns.  The greater the number of matching columns, the more weight I want to attach to the matched `data`column.

This is how I am going about the process

**Step 1 - read the relevant rows into a TEMP table**

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE H1 AS SELECT * FROM valency WHERE (typ = T) AND (entity = E);
```

**Set the `v0..v5`values to 1 or 0 depending on whether they match**

```
UPDATE H1 SET 
v0 = CASE WHEN (v0 = V0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
v1 = CASE WHEN (v1 = V1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
v2 = CASE WHEN (v2 = V2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
v3 = CASE WHEN (v3 = V3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
v4 = CASE WHEN (v4 = V4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
v5 = CASE WHEN (v5 = V5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END;
```

This will typically result in one or more rows in `H1`with zero or more `v*`values set to 0 with the others being set to 1.  All I really care about is the "best" match - i.e. identifying the row with the biggest number of non-zero `v*`values.

**Step 3**

```
SELECT urid,lato,data,v0 + v1 + v2 + v3 + v4 + v5 as 'vSum' FROM H1 ORDER BY vSum DESC LIMIT 1;
```

which isolates the row with the "best" match.  Prior to using and manipulating the best matched `data`in this result row I use the magnitude of `vSum`to assign a weighting to the data.

This works - perfectly.  However, I am no SQL expert so I cannot help wondering if there might not be a better/simpler/faster way of accomplishing the same thing.  The context in which this has to be used does not require speed so I am not keen on a trade off that uses up more storage with more indexing.  I'd be most grateful to anyone  who could comment on my approach and suggest improvements.

Comment: You don't supply a sample dataset (or dbfiddle) to play around with, but why not do the whole thing in one `select` statement? `select *, CASE WHEN (v0 = V0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN (v1 = V1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + ... as vSum order by vSum desc`

Comment: Yes, that avoids the TEMP table.  Write that up as an answer and I will accept + upvote it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the select into one `SELECT` statement by calculating the score in one go. This eliminates the need for a temporary table and some roundtrips between your code and the database engine:

```
select
       *
     ,  CASE WHEN (v0 = V0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       +CASE WHEN (v1 = V1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       +CASE WHEN (v2 = V1) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       +CASE WHEN (v3 = V3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       +CASE WHEN (v4 = V4) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       +CASE WHEN (v5 = V5) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
       + ... as vSum
  FROM valency
 WHERE (typ = T)
   AND (entity = E)
 order by vSum desc
 limit 1
```

You may want to add more conditions to the `order by` clause to make sure your ordering remains consistent between runs.